# How to include OpenStreetMap in my Web app

Tags: openstreetmap

Well I am looking for a tutorial that tells me how to include OpenStreetMap in my web app. Google have put such a nice tutorial that tells us step by step process on how to include Google Map in our web app. but I have not come across anything like this for OSM. All I came across is how use (edit) the OSM but not how to include it in our app. All I want is, replace my Google map being used in my app with that with OSM.

Anyone please!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You haven't really explained what you actually want to do. For just displaying a map you should read the [Using Tiles](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/) section on [switch2osm](http://switch2osm.org/) and choose either [OpenLayers](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/getting-started-with-openlayers/) or [Leaflet](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/getting-started-with-leaflet/) as your preferred JavaScript library.